# Calling a function via prompt in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple calculator that uses prompt to define which function to call as part of a coding bootcamp. Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I don't want to use a switch/ifelse as that feels like it would defeat the object of using functions.

```js
/*You will need to create four functions:
● add — This function will add the two numbers together.
● subtract — This function will subtract the second number from
the first number.
● multiply — This function will multiply the two numbers together.
● divide — This function will divide the first number by the second
number.
● Your calculator should ask the user to input the first number, the second
number and what operation they would like to perform on those
numbers.
● The program should then log the calculation and the total to the console.
For example if the user inputs 6, 7 and multiply, the output would be: 6 x
7 = 42*/

//get n1, n2
let n1 = ((Number(prompt("Input your first number"))));
let n2 = ((Number(prompt("Input your second number"))));
let task =((Function(prompt ("Should I add, subtract, multiply or divide? (lowecase please!)"))));
var sym = ("");

function add (n1, n2){
  sym = ("+");
  return n1+n2;
}


function subtract (n1, n2){
  sym = ("-");
  return n1-n2;
}

function multiply (n1, n2){
  sym = ("x");
  return n1*n2;
}

function divide (n1, n2){
  sym = ("/");
  return n1/n2;
}

console.log (`${n1} ${sym} ${n2} = ${task(n1,n2)}`);
```

Tried the above - was expecting console log to read for example:
"2 + 3 = 5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks very messy, as you have a lot of unnecessary parenthesis that make no sense. I have removed them.

Secondly, I see you made a nice way to programmatically call the right function. The only thing that was done wrong was using `Function` instead of `eval`. `Function` can not access local variables, but `eval` can. There is a version with `eval` and an inline, more efficient version.

Let me know if there are any problems.

```js
let n1 = Number(prompt("Input your first number"));
let n2 = Number(prompt("Input your second number"));
let task = prompt("Should I add, subtract, multiply or divide?").toLowerCase();
var sym = "";

if (task !== "add" && task !== "subtract" && task !== "multiply" && task !== "divide") {
  alert("Invalid Operator!");
}

function add (n1, n2){
  sym = "+";
  return n1+n2;
}

function subtract (n1, n2){
  sym = "-";
  return n1-n2;
}

function multiply (n1, n2){
  sym = "*";
  return n1*n2;
}

function divide (n1, n2){
  sym = "/";
  return n1/n2;
}

var ans = eval(`${task}(${n1}, ${n2})`)

console.log(`${n1} ${sym} ${n2} = ${ans}`);
```

I also decided to make a really inline version, just incase you wanted some shorter code:

```js
let n1 = Number(prompt("Input your first number"));
let n2 = Number(prompt("Input your second number"));
let task = prompt("Should I add, subtract, multiply or divide?").toLowerCase();

if (task !== "add" && task !== "subtract" && task !== "multiply" && task !== "divide") {
  alert("Invalid Operator!");
}

const operations = {
  add: function(n1, n2) { return n1 + n2; },
  subtract: function(n1, n2) { return n1 - n2; },
  multiply: function(n1, n2) { return n1 * n2; },
  divide: function(n1, n2) { return n1 / n2; },
}

const symbols = {
  add: "+",
  subtract: "-",
  multiply: "*",
  divide: "/"
}

console.log(`${n1} ${symbols[task]} ${n2} = ${operations[task](n1, n2)}`);
```

Comment: thanks for that - is there any way to do it without the switch?

Comment: I'll tinker with it, and get back to you if I get a better solution.

Comment: Figured it out. `Function` doesn't give access to local variables, but `eval` works for that. I also added an if statement to check for an incorrect operator, just in case. Operators are now also converted automatically to lowercase.

Comment: I also added an inline version, for fun

Comment: @David Can you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , using if/else or switches would make the code lengthy , what you can use is objects to map all the functions in one place to access it and do the same with symbols , here is the code for it

```js
/*You will need to create four functions:
● add — This function will add the two numbers together.
● subtract — This function will subtract the second number from
the first number.
● multiply — This function will multiply the two numbers together.
● divide — This function will divide the first number by the second
number.
● Your calculator should ask the user to input the first number, the second
number and what operation they would like to perform on those
numbers.
● The program should then log the calculation and the total to the console.
For example if the user inputs 6, 7 and multiply, the output would be: 6 x
7 = 42*/

//get n1, n2
let n1 = ((Number(prompt("Input your first number"))));
let n2 = ((Number(prompt("Input your second number"))));
let task = (prompt("Should I add, subtract, multiply or divide? (lowecase please!)"));
var sym = ("");

function add(n1, n2) {
  sym = ("+");
  return n1 + n2;
}


function subtract(n1, n2) {
  sym = ("-");
  return n1 - n2;
}

function multiply(n1, n2) {
  sym = ("x");
  return n1 * n2;
}

function divide(n1, n2) {
  sym = ("/");
  return n1 / n2;
}
const tasks = {
  "add": add,
  "subtract": subtract,
  "multiply": multiply,
  "divide": divide
};
const symbol = {
  "add": "+",
  "subtract": "-",
  "multiply": "*",
  "divide": '/'
};
console.log(`${n1} ${sym} ${n2} = ${tasks[task](n1,n2)}`);
```